# Order of Parameters in find

Tags: unix, find, solaris

Should it matter in which order you specify the criteria in a `find` command? On Solaris,

```
find /my/directory ! -type d -mtime -3 -ls
```

doesn't find directories, but

```
find /my/directory -mtime -3 -ls ! -type d
```

does.  The man page seems to state that each primary is treated in isolation as a Boolean expression, and the results just ANDed together, and that the `-ls` primary is just one that happens always to return TRUE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-ls` is an action for `find`.

When you say:

```
find /my/directory -mtime -3 -ls ! -type d
```

the part after `-ls` is essentially ignored and you get the same results as you'd get by saying:

```
find /my/directory -mtime -3 -ls
```

Comment: @rojomoke I don't know about Solaris, but the GNU find manpage mentions "evaluating the given expression from left to right, according to the rules of precedence".

Comment: @rojomoke Solaris `find` manual page states the primaries are concatenated in your case. A concatenation is definitely ordered. Note also that the `! -type d` has no effect only because it is not followed by any action.